# Searching and and ampersand

Tags: full-text-search

I have a php/mysql directory. If someone searches a company name like "Johnson & Johnson" and it's it the DB as "Johnson and Johnson" it doesn't match.

I'm doing a NAME LIKE '% var %' kind of search currently. Is there an easy way to get this to work? I'm not sure if it's just a matter of setting up the table as INNODB with full text on the column or if there's more involved.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need a more sophisticated search capable of tokenising the search terms and searching through a tokenised index. You could probably get some of the way there with a full text search in the InnoDB table engine, but you could also look at other options. Some that you could consider:

- [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)
- [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)
- [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/)

All of these are more sophisticated full text indexers and searchers than you will get built into a database engine, but will require more work to get set up and going than a mysql full text search too, so it depends on the features you need.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement of `&` by `and` is not really a trivial task in my book.

You may fare better by doing that kind of replacement beforehand, using a set of pre-defined rules (e.g. "&" and "+" become "and").